# Integrating $\sqrt{1+\cos^2}$

Tags: integration, trigonometry

As part of my Calculus II final we had a bonus question that had $$\int \sin(x)\sqrt{1+\cos^2(x)} \, dx \tag{*} $$ This set-up integral was not given and I know that (*) is easy to solve with U-Substitution.

As part of my incorrect set-up of the problem I wrote the integral as $$\int \sqrt{1+\cos^2(x)} \, dx \tag{**} $$

Try as I might with 1/2 Angles and Identities I was at a loss as how to approach an integral like (**). I ended up sitting till the end of the period without thinking of a method to approach the problem with.

So, how do you solve an integral like (**) that is resistant to the application of 1/2 Angle and Identity relationships? and what will put me on track to complete this integration?

Comment: Wolfram alpha indicates that the answer is an elliptic function: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int+sqrt%281%2Bcos%5E2%28x%29%29  in other words, you can't do it  "by hand" -- the answer is a "new" function.

Comment: Legendre didn't have a computer. How do you get to that "new" function? What is the method for evaluation?

Comment: Wait, so the bonus question was over ($*$) or  ($**$) ? You are correct that ($*$) is solved using two u-substitutions, and Bill Cook is correct in saying ($**$) is "solved" using elliptic functions... i.e., a function which is defined to be an integral. I couldn't imagine the teacher would assign ($**$) which is not used to "solve" for ($*$).

Comment: The bonus involved the surface area of curves of revolution to the effect of $$ SA = \int f(x) \sqrt{1+f'(x)} dx $$ and I simply applied the wrong formula leaving out the f(x). The teacher assigned a workable Calc II problem but apparently my failed set-up is a bit of a bottomless pit.

Comment: Have you tried with $u=\cos x$, so $du =-\sin xdx$,$$\int{\sin x\sqrt{1+\cos^2x}dx}=-\int{\sqrt{1+u^2}du}?$$

Comment: @MarioG That is the correct method for the correct formula. However my question pertains the incorrect set-up given in (**)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a partial answer to the question in your comment, "how do you get to that new function?"

The function in this case is an elliptic integral of the second kind,
$$E(\phi,k)=\int_0^\phi \sqrt{1-k^2\sin^2\theta}\,d\theta\ .$$
To evaluate your integral in these terms,
$$\eqalign{\int \sqrt{1+\cos^2x}\,dx
  &=\int_0^x\sqrt{1+\cos^2\theta}\,d\theta+C\cr
  &=\int_0^x\sqrt{2-\sin^2\theta}\,d\theta+C\cr
  &=\sqrt2\int_0^x\sqrt{1-{\textstyle\frac{1}{2}}\sin^2\theta}\,d\theta+C\cr
  &=\sqrt2 E(x,{\textstyle\frac{1}{\sqrt2}})+C\ .\cr}$$
The Wolfram Alpha link given in one of the comments looks different from this, though if you carefully read the documentation you will see that they are just using a different notation.

As to how you evaluate this function, well really just the same as any other function - by finding out lots of facts about it.  For example, it is obvious from the definition that
$$E(\phi,-k)=E(\phi,k)$$
and that
$$\frac{d}{d\phi}E(\phi,k)=\sqrt{1-k^2\sin^2\phi}\ .$$
Also, by substituting $t=\sin\theta$ or $z=\tan(\theta/2)$ you can derive the alternative formulae
$$E(\phi,k)=\int_0^{\sin\phi} \sqrt{\frac{1-k^2t^2}{1-t^2}}\,dt
  =\int_0^{\tan(\phi/2)}\!\!\sqrt{1+(2-4k^2)z^2+z^4}\frac{dz}{(1+z^2)^2}\ .$$
And so on. . .

To actually get a numerical evaluation for a given $x$ you could use standard integral estimation methods such as Simpson's Rule, or you could calculate a Taylor series.  As I am not an expert in numerical methods, there could very well be techniques which are superior to either of these.  If you Google something like "elliptic integral numeric evaluation" I would think that you should find something.

Comment: Thanks for the response, sorry for my own delay. I've been trying, mostly failing, at reading up on the subject. There is a great deal going on that is beyond my freshman understanding of mathematics. I've got a few books on order. Thankyou for your help.